# reset 'random' math

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, reset

I've got a random generator my using arrays and the following string to randomize:

```
var doelgroepRand = doelgroepArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * doelgroepArray.length)];
```

/

```
var divergeerIdee = 'Laat een' + ' ' + doelgroepRand + ' ' + watRand + ' ' + handelingRand
```

This goes into

```
$('#something').click( function() { 
event.preventDefault();
alert(divergeerIdee); });
});
```

But to get a new set of random items, you need to refresh the page.
I want that, on click, everything is 'resetted' and you get new random items.

What is the string I need?

Comment: Place your first two lines inside the click event.

Answer (score 1):

Simply pack it all in a javascript function. E.g.:

```
function createRandom() {
  var doelgroepRand = doelgroepArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * doelgroepArray.length)];
  return divergeerIdee = 'Laat een' + ' ' + doelgroepRand + ' ' + watRand + ' ' + handelingRand
}


$('#something').click( function() { 
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(createRandom()); 
    alert(createRandom()); 
  });
});
```